# Can I add arbitrary data to package.json and how?

Tags: npm

I have a browser-based application that has a package.json (for managing dependencies using node.js).

However, I'd like to add some json meta-data to my app and I have two options: either create a new json file and add the data, or add it to the package.json.

The question is:

1. Is it recommended to add application-specific non-standard meta-data to package.json?
2. Where can I add this data? Under which key? `_my_data` seems to be a good key, but I couldn't find any standard documentation about this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are free to add arbitrary fields to package.json (and npm will not complain).  So long as the file is valid JSON, `npm` will look for the relevant fields (e.g. `dependencies` for `npm install`) and won't complain about additional fields

Assuming your dependencies are standard, the "recommended" approach is to keep a separate JSON file for non-standard data.  This way, you can just copy or link to the standard package.json (and you are free to use arbitrary fields in your specific JSON file)